# How to access JavaScript module pattern in my case?

Tags: javascript, module

I have defined the following module in **MyModule.js**:

**MyModule.js:**

```
MyModule = {

    controller: {
       paintCar: function(color){
            //PAINTING PROCESS
       }
    },

    tester: {
        ...
    },

};
```

Then, I have another javascript file, **other.js**:

**other.js**:

```
MyModule.controller.paintCar('red');
```

My index.html

```
<body>
    <script scr="MyModule.js"></script>
    <script src="other.js"></script>
  </body>
```

All these files are put under WebContent directory of Eclipse Dynamic Web Project.

In **other.js** when I try to run the above code, I got error "**MyModule is not defined**".  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelt `src` here: `<script scr="MyModule.js">`. This would have been picked up by [basic automated QA testing](http://validator.w3.org/).

(Original answer before the theory was confirmed) Presumably, because you aren't loading the script files properly. Since you haven't shown us the code that does that (or even told us what environment you are using) it is hard to say exactly how you went wrong.

Assuming you are using client side JS in a webpage, your code should look something like:

```
<script src="MyModule.js"></script>
<script src="other.js"></script>
```

Order is significant. End tags are mandatory. Self-closing tag syntax is unacceptable (unless the document is served as application/xhtml+xml)

(This uses HTML 5 syntax. For HTML 4 / XHTML 1, add a type attribute. For HTML 3.2, add a language attribute)

Comment: It is the HTML that causes the scripts to be loaded, and you haven't shown us any of that. (he said, in response to a comment that has since been deleted)

Comment: I updated my post. I have loaded the js files in my index.html

Comment: Updated answer. See first line.

Comment: By the way, in JS, is the module name and the js file name must be the same or not?

Comment: @Mellon: The filename is not related to the "module" name at all. JavaScript doesn't have modules, just objects.

Comment: "module" is just a buzzword. All this is is an object. The file names are irrelevant (more that than, as far as the browser is concerned, there aren't even any file names, they are just URIs).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned your environment, but generally you have to ensure that the JavaScript in `MyModule.js` is executed before the JavaScript in `other.js`, because you need `MyModule.js` to set up the `MyModule` variable.

How you do it will vary by environment. In a web browser, you'd do that by putting in two `script` tags, first one for `MyModule.js` then the one for `other.js` (although frequently, for use on websites, you want to have a build process that combines your scripts into a single file to minimize HTTP requests). In NodeJS, there's the whole `require` mechanism.

**Update** based on your edit:

Looks like a typo:

```
<body>
    <script scr="MyModule.js"></script>
             ^^-- here, they're transposed
    <script src="other.js"></script>
</body>
```

If that typo isn't really in your file, then look to see that the files are where the web server expects, that the web server isn't being thrown by capitalisation, that sort of thing. Fundamentally, that's correct.

Comment: I updated my post. I have loaded the js files in my index.html

Comment: Yes, it is a typo. Thank you:)